# How to print/code multi-line html5/javascript within a php functions?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm fairly new to the world of webdev and have come across a small issue. I'm trying to implement a "zoom" functionality to a canvas diagram and need to add java functions but I'm not sure this is the way to go:

```
print "document.getElementById(\"plus\").addEventListener("click", function(){";
print " scale /= scaleMultiplier;";
print " draw(scale, translatePos);";
print "}, false);";
```

Is this the right way to add multiple lines of Javascript/html5 code within php functions?

Just in case its needed, my function:

```
function draw($num_of_exons, $start_positions, $end_positions, $start_first_exon, $end_last_exon, $target_pos, $coding_region_start, $coding_region_end, $canvas_x){

//Variable initilisations
//variable initialization removed  

//Sort out target positions
//variable initialization removed 

//Main Diagram

print "<canvas id=\"$canvas_x\" width=$CANVAS_WIDTH height=$CANVAS_HEIGHT     style=\"border:1px solid #c3c3c3;\">";
print "Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.";
print "</canvas>";

print "<script>";
print "var c = document.getElementById(\"$canvas_x\");";
print "var ctx = c.getContext(\"2d\");";
print "ctx.fillStyle = \"#273c61\";"; // colour

//CODING REGION

print "ctx.fillStyle = \"#80d04b\";"; //rect colour
print "ctx.fillRect($coding_start,$CODING_REGION_POSITION_CANVAS,($coding_end - $coding_start), $CODING_REGION_HEIGHT);"; //draw rectangle

for($x = 0; $x < $num_of_exons; $x++) {

    $start_pos = $start_positions[$x];
    $start_pos = scale($start_pos, $start_first_exon, $end_last_exon, $new_range_min, $new_range_max);

    $end_pos = $end_positions[$x];
    $end_pos = scale($end_pos, $start_first_exon, $end_last_exon, $new_range_min, $new_range_max);

    print "ctx.fillStyle = \"#41BFFF\";"; //rect colour
    print "ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;";
    print "ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;";
    print "ctx.shadowBlur = 1;";
    print "ctx.shadowColor = \"rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 )\";";
    print "ctx.fillRect($start_pos,$ITEM_POSITION_CANVAS,($end_pos - $start_pos),$RECT_HEIGHT);"; //draw rectangle

    drawexonlines($x, $end_positions, $start_first_exon, $end_last_exon, $new_range_min, $new_range_max, $start_pos, $line_offset);
}

printtargets($target_pos_split_start, $start_first_exon, $target_pos_split_end, $end_last_exon, $new_range_min, $new_range_max, $ITEM_POSITION_CANVAS, $RECT_HEIGHT);

print "</script>";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely you will get a solid answer on this, as it is an opinion based question (coding style) and is quite broad.

With that said, I'd advise heavily against this coding style. There's no real reason to write your code like this - it's tedious, and even your example has errors. Without seeing more code, it's very hard to understand why you would need to write this type of logic with PHP, and why this can't just be written purely in JavaScript.

---

If you need to pass data from PHP to JavaScript you can `echo` values into JS variables. Using `JSON` as a bridge is a clean way to transfer PHP data over to JS, and create basic objects to work with. Here's a simple example.

```
<?php
  $phpVal = array(
    'numbers' => 7,
    'strings' => 'hello',
    'arrays' => array('one', 'two'),
    'objects' => array('property' => 'value')
  );
?>

..

<script>
  var jsVal = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($phpVal); ?>);
  console.log(jsVal.numbers); // >> 7
  console.log(jsVal.strings); // >> "hello"
  console.log(jsVal.arrays);  // >> ["one", "two"]
  console.log(jsVal.objects); // >> Object {property: "value"}
</script>
```

Consider using this pattern to create objects with all the data you need, that you can then use with regularly written JavaScript.

---

Some reading material.

PHP

- [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)
- [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

JS

- [`Objects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [`JSON Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

---

Side note:

> need to add java functions

JavaScript !== Java. Don't get these two languages confused, they are not *directly* related. If you need a shorthand for JavaScript, call it JS. Referring to JS functions as *java functions* is simply incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Definitely helped a lot!